# How to create react app with visual studio 2017 (no visual studio code)

Tags: c#, reactjs, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

I need create react app that create in visual studio and working with simple "F5" key. I don't need create react project C# in visual studio because this project type (Microsoft react project) have not my standards.

my reason for don't use Microsoft react project sample is :

the negative point of Microsoft react project for me is that project type have server side programming in client side and from the other hand Microsoft force me to use type script and give me much useless dependencies i never use in my project.
i working on a fat client (rich client) application and just call some API from client.

i need create a good infrastructure .

Comment: you mean, react.js project?

Comment: yes of course .  create-react-app  need compile with nodejs i don't want use that and complex solutions

Comment: you can use command line or powershell to do that. Then open it on visual studio 2017 if you don't want on visual studio code.

Comment: i want create a sample project that help to programmers use this example for create new project in our great "visual studio solution" we have more than 20 project in this solution and need create very simple front-end projects.

Comment: Have you considered creating your own project template?

Comment: i worked with that power shell code. is that publish and run project with just "F5" or Start key?  i need find a solution that very simple for all developers.

Comment: yes .  exactly we need create our own project template .

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx

Comment: yeah, create your template would be your possible solution.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates

Comment: command `dotnet new react`, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/react?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: guys thanks for help . all  comments are useful .

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way that may helps:

- create an empty folder outside of VS.
- create the stuff needed for a single react.js pack (index.html, etc.)
- add it as an existing website

So no .net unnecessary extras will be there.

Answer (score 0):

Best option will be create a react project outside Visual Studio. For that open up powershell or terminal and follow these steps-

1. Make sure `npm` & `node.js` is installed.
2. [Create a React.js](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html) project- `npx create-react-app my-app`
3. You can either import this project into Visual Studio or install [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and open project there.

Visual studio code won't give you an option for running app using F5 key but you can open terminal (shortcut- ctrl + `) and type `npm start`